# Aggregation of Json objects on a relational table on Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have a relational table that contains three variable values, an ID, and the date broken down into parts.

```
ID | Year | Month | Day | A | B | C | 
 1   2019     12    01    5   10  15
 1   2019     12    02    2   4   6 
 1   2019     11    01    1   2   3
 1   2019     11    02    10  9   8
```

The goal is to aggregate that data into a JSONB/Relational Table, with the columns A, B, and C in a JSONB object: {A:5, B:10, C:15} which is the value to another JSONB object with the Day as the key.

```
{01:{A:5, B:10, C:15}}
```

Additionally, I want to aggregate the data so that all of the data for every month is within one object, with the final result looking like the following:

```
ID | Year | Month | Data                                     |
 1   2019    12     {01:{A:5, B:10, C:15},02:{A:2, B:4, C:6}}
 1   2019    11     {01:{A:1, B:2, C:3},02:{A:10, B:9, C:8}}
```

I've been able to get as far as creating an the data with a row for every day, but I'm getting stuck on aggregating them all by month, year, and ID.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Please also include the query that you managed to write in your question, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `json_build_object()` and `json_object_agg()`:

```
select
    id,
    year,
    month,
    json_object_agg(day, json_build_object('A', A, 'B', B, 'C', C)) "data"
from mytable
group by
    id,
    year,
    month
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkYuhUGG6yTTLWQap2m9y3/2)**:

```
| id  | year | month | data                                                |
| --- | ---- | ----- | --------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | 2019 | 11    | {"1":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},"2":{"A":10,"B":9,"C":8}}  |
| 1   | 2019 | 12    | {"1":{"A":5,"B":10,"C":15},"2":{"A":2,"B":4,"C":6}} |
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much, I was over thinking it.

Comment: Welcome @ChristopherCarlisle! Glad that it helped.